# Can I use the logo of an ISO standard in an open document

Tags: copyright, trademark, creative-commons

In the frame of a European H2020 project, we are creating educational content for companies on the topic of energy efficiency in industry. The educational content will be made publicly available under a **Creative Commons license** on an online platform in the form of editable Word documents and Powerpoint presentations. The idea is that companies with access to the material will be able to modify the documents to suit their specific needs (e.g. add their logos, adapt or translate the text...).

**In this context, I would like to know if it is possible to incorporate freely (i.e. without asking any sort of permission) the logo of an ISO standard in a Powerpoint presentation that will be made available on an online platform?**

More generally, my question applies to other types of logos (companies, associations...)?

Comment: Info here: https://www.iso.org/iso-name-and-logo.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have sent an e-mail to logo@iso.org to ask for clarification/permission. I will let you know what they have answered for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer which I got from an ISO customer service representative:

> There are no ISO 50001 logo. The main ISO logo (ISO + globe design) is a registered mark and use of the ISO logo is in principle granted only to ISO members, i.e. the national standards institutes which represent ISO in their respective countries. Use of the ISO logo is not authorized in connection with certification since this would give the impression that it is ISO that has carried out the certification or has approved it, whereas ISO develops and maintains ISO international standards but does not itself carry out any certification. Nor does ISO issue certificates related to certification or keep a register of certified companies. These activities are carried out independently of ISO by numerous certification bodies in operation around the world.
>
> Logos displaying certification marks are issued by a certification body. Therefore, you will need to reach out to the certification body having issued the logo.

Not sure that this actually answers the question as he is referring to using the ISO logo in connection with certification, not in the context of making it appear in presentations for educational purposes.